# Access local server from other computers on my network

Tags: java, google-app-engine, networking, localhost

I have a server on my computer and I set `--address=0.0.0.0` so that I can access it from other computers in my network. Now my question is, what do the other computers type as the address so they may access the server? On the hosting computer, I can simply do `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: This is a ServerFault question (for server admins and DBA's), not a StackOverflow question (for coders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://<your-ipaddress>:8080
```

Make sure your firewall permits TCP on port 8080

Comment: How would I find my ip address in osx

Comment: open a terminal and type `ifconfig`. It will be under inet on an interface that's active. It will probuby look like 10.0.0.12 or 192.168.1.23

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned above, a lot of stuff is showing. Which one do I use? inet? broadcast? they both start with 192

Comment: if you have wifi and ethernet on you could use the inet of either

Comment: It will also be in the gui. System Preference > Network > Status > address of a connection with a green jelly.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what OS you are running..

Windows:

in command prompt type

```
ipconfig /all | find "IP Address"
```

for linux:

in shell type

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
```

You need to find your internal network IP adress
this will look something like 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.* 
This all depends on your configuration

this will be the IP your clients use to connect

Comment: on mac osx I type ipconfig and ended up with a lot of stuff. Which one do I use? inet? broadcast?

Comment: you would use inet.
on mac the correct command is ifconfig, I believe

Comment: no problem. For other people looking for the answer, just saying. I think mine was clearly the correct one... Nothing against jeremyjjbrown of course.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown answered the original problem `http://<your-ipaddress>:8080`. You helped fill in the subsequent details. That's the criteria I used. So I upvoted you and gave him the check mark. If I could check mark both I would.